# Shape/element behind a.link in different text types?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a shape that would appear behind text links on a website. I have searched online and via the forums here and it may be my ignorance but I can't seem to find any matching responses that demonstrate how this is achieved in a similar way to what I am trying to do. Ideally the shape does not interfere with text alignment and could sit behind some text or extend beyond the edges of the text container for different sized text eg. h1 or p etc.

I have attached an example of what I am trying to achieve with different sized text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If it is not obvious I am new to building with html and css so please forgive any ignorance.

Examples of shape behind various text types
[image: examples of shape behind various text types]

Edit 1: I have tried this jsfiddle[dot]net/broahhhh/2pstw693/15/ but the image repeats itself to fit the text size and it cuts off at the edges of the text.

Cheers

Comment: Show us what have you tried. So that we can work on and help you.

Comment: Maybe you need something like that? `Loren ipsum <span style="background-color:#FECAFA">dolor sit</span> amet`

Comment: I tried this but I can't get the image element to fit to the text size without it repeating itself: https://jsfiddle.net/broahhhh/2pstw693/15/

Comment: `a.fancy-background{ background-size: 100% auto }`

Comment: @mrReiha i have tried this but the element still repeats itself to fill the area.

Comment: @hk_fellow this adds a colour which is good but how would I shape the span with the appropriate padding?

Comment: @noahscott that's impossible man. [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exr0pzhy/) green one has `background-size`. by the way, this is just a work-around. if you want a solution which works on every situations u need to stick to **svg**

Comment: @mrReiha thank you for showing me an example. How would SVG work better though? How would it be implemented to achieve the effect?

Comment: @noahscott It's really a difficult question ( at least for me ) to answer, I'm not an SVG expert, but the current solution will fail for long texts and won't generate a pixel-perfect and high-quality output.